# How make a SAP UI5 Form look like this?

Tags: sapui5

I am building a Form with sap ui5
Any idea how I can obtain a layout similar to this using SAP UI5?
[image: form layout]

I tried using sap ui5 tags form and layout but could not find how to make the tables like in the picture

Answer (score 0):

If you want a similar layout with the spacing and details as mentioned in the image, I'm afraid you can't. Creat a smart form using Responsive Grid Layout. However the layout of having 3 tables side by side can be achieved, by using the Table control within the HBox/HoirzontalLayout control. Bind the table using Id's.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid + VBox + HBox to build custom layout. Please refer to this blog [Transform your paper forms into Digital forms](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/27/transform-your-paper-forms-into-digital-forms-using-sapui5/)